# How to [in a text file] for each line create a new file named after the first column and containing all the remaining columns of each line?

Tags: search, text, awk, sed, grep

I have a file like the following

Columns are delimited by tabs

```
    Group1  name1:ENSG0365  name4:ENSMU0000196  name2:ENSMU00001826
    Group2  name2:ENS000132622  name4:ENSUS00074793 
    Group3  name3:ENSFP000844   name1:ENSMU000025
```

I want a list of files for every line, named after the 1st Column (Group1, Group2, etc) and looking like this

name1:ENSG0365
name4:ENSMU0000196
mouse2:ENSMU00001826

I don't know which tools is better for this task. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash 4:

```
while read -r name rest; do echo "$rest" >"$name"; done </path/to/your/file
```

Update:

```
while read -r name rest; do printf "%s\n" $rest >"$name"; done < /path/to/your/file
```

Comment: so If my file is called Groups.txt the line would be 

'while read -r file rest; do echo "$rest" > $file; done < Groups.txt'

This didn't work. It didn't generate a file. How does this code split/arrange every column?

using bash 4.3.42

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong folder to try the script, It already worked but it didn't split them one line per column. Is there a way to fix it?

the files look like this now



         'name3:ENSFP000844   name1:ENSMU000025'

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -n -e '@x=split;open(F,">".shift(@x));$,="\n";print F @x' < groups.txt
```

Taking a wild guess at what you mean in the comment, you could try:

```
perl -n -e '@x=split /\t/;open(F,">".shift(@x));$,="\n";print F @x' < groups.txt
```

Comment: Your code did the trick. Now that I tried with another example, I need to extract a separate line for each block but avoid spliting in new lines the whitespaces, only split according to TAB.

An alternative trick would be splitting only the elements like this name:XX XX XXX(+)    name1:XX XX(+) ; each one separated in a different line. The element can end either in (+) or (-)

Comment: @AndrésParada Sorry I can't understand what you're saying. Why don't you change the question and its examples to be correct?

Comment: @AndrésParada Great. It would be good to accept the answer, then.

Comment: I am a newbie sorry, I didn't know about the thick {another user warned me and I noticed that seconds ago too}. Thanks for your help.